# Automapper will not ignore property

Tags: automapper

I have a mapping between two classes:

```
CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(b => b.Foo, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(a => a.Aoo.Foo))
    .ReverseMap()
    .IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter()
    .IgnoreAllSourcePropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter()
    .ForMember(a => a.Aoo, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

I would expect, from the last `Ignore()` alone, that when mapping a B to an A, Automapper would not try to assign a value to A. However, I do such a thing here:

```
var a = _mapper.Map<A>(b);
```

And I get the following exception:

`System.NullReferenceException : typeMapDestination.Aoo cannot be null because it's used by ForPath.`

Why is it trying to assign a value here? I even looked at the source code and this exception only gets thrown when the setter for that property is null!

Comment: From your Exception, it doesn't try to assign it, but needs to be assigned.

Comment: Upgrade, or try ForPath->Ignore.

Comment: @Nikolaus I would normally agree, however, removing the mapping between A.Aoo.Foo and B.Foo continues to give the same error.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I am on 6.1.1, and using ForPath(b => b.Foo, opts => opts.Ignore()) doesn't work, but completely reversing the mapping did cause it to work. I will continue experimenting with order to see if I can get it to work without needing to declare the mapping as <B, A>

Comment: ```ForPath(a => a.Aoo.Foo, o=>o.Ignore());```, the MapFrom is reversed to a ForPath. See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?q=forpath+ignore&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).